# Oozie workflow fails to execute hive query using UDF with com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parse()

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, cloudera, oozie

I have created a .jar file that utilizes many functions from google.i18n.phonenumbers java package. The jar file correctly loads the necessary external libraries from `com.googlecode.libphonenumber.libphonenumber`, `com.googlecode.libphonenumber.geocoder`, `com.googlecode.libphonenumber.carrier`.

The .jar file is used to create a HIVE UDF function with the following command (on Hue Editor-Cloudera 6.x):

--command (1):

```
create function func_name as 'util.ParserUtil';
```

The .jar file is located on `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/lib/hive/` for the command (1) above to execute successfully.

However, the udf function `func_name` is used in a SQL query file located on hdfs. Here is the problem:

- When the SQL query is executed through Oozie workflow (spawning an execute.sql file) the Oozie throws the below exception:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/i18n/phonenumbers/Phonenumber$PhoneNumber;

, which is awkward since the jar file has both the `com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.parse()` and `com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/Phonenumber$PhoneNumber` classes ([github](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/tree/master/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers)).

- When the same SQL query is executed through Hive Editor on Hue or a beeline query it's successfully completed.

Thus, in my guess I must apply one of the following three solutions:

1. (this is my current configuration) Can oozie take into consideration the .jar file when it's located explicitly at `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/lib/hive/`?, when running the workflow.
2. Or shall I upload the .jar file (that creates the UDF and includes the necessary java classes from google.i18n) on hdfs path `/user/oozie/share/lib/hive/`
3. Or upload .jar file on a lib folder on hdfs like `/user/src/myFile.jar` and provide that path on oozie workflow .xml file like `<file>hdfs://user/src/myFile.jar</file>`? As a result the oozie workflow will execute correctly the hive udf function from myFile.jar.

Does point (1) suffice or should I apply one of the points (2), (3)?

Comment: This is most probably caused by diferent classes loaded b oozie

Comment: Yes, I have actually resolved the issue.. The server node where the jar was located had an older version of the jar when the HIVE udf function was created.